# Running built application (Bamboo)

Tags: centos, localhost, bamboo

With my centOS running Bamboo Server, I have configured plans to build applications whenever a new code gets commited on a certain branch in the project repo on bitbucket.

But i am unable to run the built application on any device on the server how to access the application ?

Comment: What is the error message you encounter when you try to run the built application?

Comment: no errors just the URL of the application on the server (IP:port or localhost:port) is not accessible

Comment: Well, with CentOS my first guess would be selinux, but it could be anything. Look at log files and provide actual error messages instead of just saying "not accessible", the error messages provide more information than you think.

Comment: I mean when i run the built application on Bamboo, i expect that the application should at least be accessible through localhost on the server right ?